# how to make two responsive section using bootstrap 4?

Tags: css

I have two section box 1. Virtual cards & 2.Physcial cards.

Need help how to make two section div in bootstrap?

I have tried but when I view this in responsive the height shuffles of both sections div.

Let me how to keep the gap in this two-section?

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Virtual cards -->
        <div class="col-sm-6 ">
            <h3 style="text-align: center; height: 45px;background-color: 
             #FFC107">Virtual cards</h3>
            <div><img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="image-01.png"  
             style="width:50%" >
            </div>enter code here
            <div>
                <h3 style="text-align: center; height: 45px;background-color: 
                #FFC107">Block</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Physical Cards -->
        <div class="col-sm-6 ">
            <h3 style="text-align: center; height: 45px;background-color: 
              #FFC107">Physical cards</h3>
            <div><img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="image/layer- 
                 3.png">
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3 style="text-align: center;">One For All</h3>
                <p style="text-align: center;">A single cards for all 
                  purchase</p>
            </div>
            <div><h3 style="text-align: center; height: 45px;background- 
              color: #FFC107">Block</h3>
            </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
```

Comment: gap? what gap ? do you mean spacesbtween them?

Comment: same height for every .col-sm-6? Is this the gap you're talking about?

Comment: no I mean there are 2 box section, both have has header than below that img block after that  one block in which I have to place 3 small size img.  All this shloud be responsive

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column-reverse">
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```